# how can I store DayOfWeek and a Time in CoreData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

How best could I store day-of-week and a time within core data?   For example:

- Mon 4.05am
- Wed 8.10pm

I can represent this within Objective-C using NSDateComponents however this type isn't listed in the core data attributes type drop down list. For that matter these doesn't seem to be an NSTime type either in Objective-C or core data.  Options that come to mind:

- store as string and then have to parse (e.g. "Mon 5.00pm") however that doesn't sound ideal
- store as (a) NSInteger for day-of-week, and (b) NSDate for time, and only use the time portion when accessing later?
- other better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the classes representing your data conform to the NSCoding protocol you can make use of [Transformable Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1). A short quote from Apple's chapter [Non-Standard Persistent Attributes pf Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1):

> The idea behind transformable
>   attributes is that you access an
>   attribute as a non-standard type, but
>   behind the scenes Core Data uses an
>   instance of NSValueTransformer to
>   convert the attribute to and from an
>   instance of NSData. Core Data then
>   stores the data instance to the
>   persistent store.

NSDateComponent does conform to the protocol :)

Comment: by the way - excellent works well - except I did find I had to set the year too otherwise I would get weird results when accessing day-of-week (almost seems like like a bug)

Comment: Did you save the data as NSDateComponents?